# How to join multiple path objects into a combined path object in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I'm attaching an image for demonstration since this is hard to explain.

I want to ad text description to an image map, but I don't want tons of paths, one for each letter...I would like to group a section of the image with a series of characters, a "string" of text.

Would like to merge them in a single path , so when I save as optimized SVG I have less code than if I had a path for every single characters...

Attaching image to explain, hope it's clear enough[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYPEY.png)

Comment: Why do you convert text to path at all?

Answer (score 5):

In Inkscape *Path > Combine* will combine all the paths to one object, but then one object can only have one fill.

So, I'm not sure how well that work for you, since the map part is a different colour.  I suppose you could add a gradient fill, then edit the gradient stops.

For example:

[image]

One more thing to note is that creating one combined path will not reduce the number of nodes.  I see the map part of your example has lots of nodes, so you might want to consider simplifying the shape a little if the file size is going to be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

i done some research how to merge object in one path, see in inkscape , Frist select the object you want to merge, than group selected objects <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>, after drag and select the objects go to path-Union <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>